# Using preg_replace()?

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand the function preg_replace(), but it looks rather cryptic to me. From looking at the documentation on the function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). I understand that it consists of three things - the subject, the pattern for matching, and what to replace it with.

I'm currently trying to 'sanitize' numerical input by replacing anything that isn't a number. So far I know I would need to allow the numbers 0-9, but remove anything that isn't a number and replace it with: "".

Instead of escaping every character I need to, is there some way to simply not allow any other character than the numbers 0-9? Also if anyone could shed light on how the 'pattern for matching' part works...

Comment: [Suggested starting point](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: @MarkBaker That was helpful! Thank you. So basically I'd have to do something like ^[0-9] to replace anything that isn't a number. I think.

Comment: `preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $subject);` ?

Comment: `[^0-9]`, not `^[0-9]`.... the latter is using `^` as a placeholder meaning the beginning of the string; the former is using `^` to mean `not`

Comment: Oh, thank you! @Sebas, why did you add the +?

Comment: it's superfluous in this case, the + means 'at least one' but in your case it doesnt matter (I guess?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sanitize a string to replace anything that isn't a number, you would write a regular expression that matches characters not in list.

The pattern `[0-9]` would match all numerals. Placing a caret (`^`) at the beginning of the set matches everything that *isn't* in the set: `[^0-9]`

```
$result = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $input);
```

Note that this will also filter out periods/decimal points and other mathematical marks. You could include periods/decimal points (allowing floats) by making the period allowed:

```
$result = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $input);
```

Note that the period (`.`) is the wildcard character in regular expressions. It doesn't need to be escaped in a bracket expression, but it would elsewhere in the pattern.

Comment: What do the escapes next to the [^0-9] represent? Does it sort of mean 'there is a pattern between these two escapes, look for it'?

Comment: The leading and trailing `/` characters are the "delimiters" indicating the start and end of the regular expression and separating it from any pattern modifiers: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thank you for that reference! I now see why some of these patterns look so crazy, partially because of the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

`preg_replace()` is easier than you think:

```
$p = "/[A-Z a-z]/";
$r = "";
$s = "12345t7890";

echo preg_replace($p, $r, $s);
```

Will output "123457890" - note no '6'

Comment: Thank you, this helped further my understanding. It's really difficult to understand if you don't know regular expressions or delimiters. It just looks like there is a lot going on, haha.

Comment: You're not alone - we all have to start somewhere!

Comment: it's actually really easy, the problem is that most of guides are over complicating the subject. Simple incremental explanation will make you be an expert in 2 hours

Answer (score 0):

`is_numeric();` isn't resolve your problem ?

Comment: I thought I couldn't use it at first, but I think you're right. Although I wanted to use preg_replace() just in case the user accidentally entered some kind of non-numeric character by mistake. This way it wouldn't reject their fields server-side.